# Android - How to create FAB programmatically?

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I have an app with full of custom views. When I try to create a FAB programmatically, it throws an error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.

**Here is my code.**

```
private FloatingActionButton getFAB() {
    FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(getContext());
    fab.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp));
    return fab;
}
```

**This is my app theme.**

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Change you activity theme to use an AppCompat theme

Comment: I'm already using AppCompat therme.

Comment: are you extending actionbarActivity or appCompatActivity?

Comment: extending AppCompatActivity

Comment: I have tried with actionbarActivity, same error :(

Comment: Have you verified your imports ?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this error when creating FAB? Does your app run if you comment code for FAB?

Comment: Are you asking about floating tool bar related imports?

    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;

Comment: Yes Harry, i can run the app without that code change.

Answer (score 8):

Fixed by using theme wrapper. But still I'm surprised about using **ContextThemeWrapper**

```
private FloatingActionButton getFAB() {
    Context context = new android.support.v7.internal.view.ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.AppTheme);
    FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(context);
    return fab;
}
```